# Formatando strings com ".format" e "%"

Tags: python

Faz um tempo que sempre que estou estudando algum código python me deparo com esta situação.

Algumas pessoas formatam o código utilizando o ".format":

```
fruta = "Maça"
print("Eu gosto de {0}!".format(fruta))
```

E outras utilizam o "%"

```
fruta = "Maça"
print("Eu gosto de %s!" % fruta)
```

Minha questão é:

Existe alguma diferença entre estas duas formas? Seja na questão performática ou algo assim?

Comment: Obviamente existe, mas são diferenças ínfimas e que você nem deveria se preocupar em aplicações de verdade.

Comment: Imaginei que não haveria real diferença, mas realmente fiquei curioso em saber por que o python apresenta duas soluções para o mesmo problema. Já que uma das frases da PEP 20 é "Deve haver uma, e de preferência, apenas uma maneira óbvia de fazê-lo."

Comment: @LINQ Existem diferenças e novas features bem interessantes que, na minha opinião, deveriam ser levadas em consideração.

Comment: Agora existe uma forma que se chama F-string que é mais legivel e performática. Se quiser dar uma olhada [neste post](https://wp.me/p9D9UD-1c) tem uns exemplos básicos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim, tem várias diferenças, várias melhorias, além do novo estilo ser muito mais elegante e pythonico, na minha opinião. Não li em lugar nenhum, é apenas achismo, mas acredito que o estilo antigo é mantido para compatibilidade com código legado.

Coloco abaixo algumas diferenças, na verdade, escolhi aquelas que não consegui fazer no formato antigo, claro que não coloquei todas, mas somente as que achei mais interessantes, para acesso a todas as features, [veja a documentação.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting)

**Com o novo estilo vc pode explicitar a posição dos argmentos:**

```
'{1} {0}'.format('Um', 'Dois')
Dois Um
```

**Escolher um caracter para pad:**

```
'{:_<9}'.format('teste')
teste____
```

**Centralização:**

```
'{:^10}'.format('teste')

        teste
```

**Argumentos nas chaves:**

```
'{nome} {sobrenome}'.format{sobrenome='Silva', nome='José')
'José Silva'
```

**Acesso a estruturas de dados (dict e list no exemplo):**

```
pessoa = {'nome': 'José', 'sobrenome': 'Silva'}
'{p[sobrenome]} {p[nome]}'.format(p=pessoa)    
'Silva José'

data = [9, 2, 43, 18, 32, 77, 99] 
'{d[3]} {d[6]}'.format(d=data)
'18,99'
```

Comment: Você deveria citar que o "novo estilo" mesmo são as f-strings - essas sim, finalmente mais práticas que o operador `%`.O método `.format`, apesar de oferecer um bom controle de como as coisas são interpoladas, sempre foi muito verboso comparado com o operador `%`.

Comment: Verdade, são tantos recursos no python, né? Na verdade nem me lembro se qdo respondi a pergunta ja tinha utilizado as f-strings.

Answer (score 2):

Na nova atualização existe mais uma opção:

```
um = 1
dois = 2

print(f'valor1:{um} valor2:{dois}')

#output: valor1:1 valor2:2
```